# JavaFX. Изменение формы элемента

Tags: java, css, javafx

Доброго времени суток!
Возник вопрос - как изменить форму Pane, например, в трапецию?
С помощью `Pane.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 0 0 5000 5000;");` можно добиться лишь закругления углов, но не прямой линии. Как добиться нужного результата?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможный вариант: рисуем необходимую форму в `svg` редакторе( я использовал `inkscape`, кривые Безье ), смотрим в `xml` ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> ) значение параметра `d` получившегося элемента, вставляем:

```
-fx-shape: "M 46.113094,144.29762 54.428572,89.869046 108.10119,90.625 126.24405,144.29762 Z";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Что если задать ось вращения по X?
Чтобы увидеть наглядно, можете скачать Scene Builder посавить Rotation Axis, например, x=3 y=0 z=1, и повернуть на 59, результат визуально похож. Поворот можно компенсировать родительским Pane-ом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]